# How can I shift a relative path up one level in make?

Tags: makefile

Sorry if this is a little esoteric, but in my makefile I have a variable $(BASE) which is a relative path.  I need to get the path *one level up*.
So if I had "../../../src", I want "../../src".
Is there way to do this easily in Make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *all* values of `BASE` for which you want to do this begin with `../`, you can try

```
$(patsubst ../%,%,$(BASE))
```

If you want to just drop the first component of an arbitrary path (i.e. a/b/c -> b/c), it takes a bit more work:

```
space := $(empty) $(empty)
shift-list = $(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1)
shift-path = $(subst $(space),/,$(call shift-list,$(subst /, ,$1)))
```

and use it as `$(call shift-path,$(BASE))`. This breaks if your paths have spaces, but handling those in `make` is a nightmare for many other reasons anyway.

Comment: I had high hopes for the simple one, as all my paths start ../, but it removed all the ../, which wasn't quite what I wanted.  The second, more complex one worked a treat!

Comment: That's strange, the `patsubst` should work fine. It certainly works for me. Can you show the code you used and the value you used it on?